# What does `const {a,b}: MyClass = foo` mean?

Tags: javascript

The source code for jest-snapshot [has this line](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/dec54a3/packages/jest-snapshot/src/index.js#L60)

```
const {currentTestName, isNot, snapshotState}: MatcherState = this;
```

While the destructuring part is fine, I don't recognize the `: MatcherState =` syntax as legal javascript. Is this something new in ES.Next or some kind of type annotation a la Flow?

Comment: Noticed the downvote. Not sure why - this is about basic javascript, not some specific code.

Comment: It's a type annotation. It's not a pure JS feature, it's typescript/flow feature.

Comment: aha, so given that it's a facebook project, it must be Flow. That should make it illegal/invalid javascript, so not sure why the file ending is *.js.